# Spring @EnableResourceServer vs @EnableOAuth2Sso

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-cloud, rest-security

Most of the tutorials I've read so far uses `@EnableOAuth2Sso` instead of `@EnableResourceServer` on the API gateway. What are the differences? What the `OAuth2Sso` does in contrast?

**Details:** I'm implementing a security/infra architecture for spring-based microservices and single page apps. For some time, while we didn't have security requirements, the SPAs talked directly to open microservices, on different hosts (CORS party).

Now I'm adding a layer of security and the gateway pattern using `spring-oauth` and `spring-zuul`. So I have a service (uaa-service) with `@EnableAuthorizationServer` and a gateway with `@EnableZuulProxy` & `@EnableResourceServer`. I only need the *password* grant type, so each SPA has it's own login form and authenticates with uaa-service token endpoint, trough the gateway, and then proceeds to use that token for further requests.

Is there anything wrong with this approach? Should I be using `@EnableOAuth2Sso`?

Comment: I wish somebody had an answer for you - I'm pretty much in the same boat. Best I can make out, the `EnableOAuth2Sso` annotation will add some http filters, that, in theory will be "oauth aware". I got the idea, for example, it will automatically pick up access tokens from incoming requests and forward to backend services. BUT, I have not gotten that working (in fact the annotation so far just broke a bunch of stuff for me - I am sure it is my lack of knowledge and not the annotation though!).

Answer (score 81):

These annotations mark your services with different [OAuth 2.0 roles](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#page-6).

**@EnableResourceServer** annotation means that your service (in terms of OAuth 2.0 - Resource Server) expects an access token in order to process the request. Access token should be obtained from Authorization Server by OAuth 2.0 Client before calling the Resource Server.

**@EnableOAuth2Sso:** marks your service as an OAuth 2.0 Client. This means that it will be responsible for redirecting Resource Owner (end user) to the Authorization Server where the user has to enter their credentials. After it's done the user is redirected back to the Client with Authorization Code (don't confuse with Access Code). Then the Client takes the Authorization Code and exchanges it for an Access Token by calling Authorization Server. Only after that, the Client can make a call to a Resource Server with Access Token.

Also, if you take a look into the source code of `@EnableOAuth2Sso` annotation you will see two interesting things:

- `@EnableOAuth2Client`. This is where your service becomes OAuth 2.0 Client. It makes it possible to forward access token (after it has been exchanged for Authorization Code) to downstream services in case you are calling those services via `OAuth2RestTemplate`.
- `@EnableConfigurationProperties(OAuth2SsoProperties.class)`. OAuth2SsoProperties has only one property `String loginPath` which is `/login` by default. This will intercept browser requests to the `/login` by `OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter` and will redirect the user to the Authorization Server.

> Should I be using @EnableOAuth2Sso?

It depends:

- If you want your API gateway to be an OAuth 2.0 client which interacts with the browser using **Authorization Code Flow** or **Resource Owner Password Credentials Flow**, then the answer is yes, you probably should. I said probably as I am not sure if `@EnableOAuth2Sso` supports Resource Owner Password Credentials Flow very well. Anyway, I would suggest you moving with Authorization Code Flow unless you have really (like really!) good reasons not to do so. BTW, when using Authorization Code Flow you may want to mark your downstream microservices as  `@EnableResourceServer`. Then the API Gateway will be OAuth 2.0 Client, and your microservices will be OAuth 2.0 Resource Servers which seems logical to me.
- If you do not need interaction with the browser (e.g. **Client Credentials Flow**) or you have SPA that makes use of **Implicit Flow** then you should use @EnableResourceServer, meaning that it will accept requests with valid Access Token only.

Comment: How did you figure out all that because I can't find a doc explains what many magical annotation or classes do for oauth2?

Comment: Most of that I figured out by investigating their source code. Also, experiments help a lot in such cases :)

Comment: What's the default configuration behind these two annotations? Is it possible to customised it?

Comment: when using @EnableOAuth2Sso it triggers ResourceServerTokenServicesConfiguration which needs endpoints like token_key to be configured that are used by ResourceServer. How to use this nice annotation in my client application without need to provide resource information?

Comment: @DanyloZatorsky   @eugene   `@EnableOAuth2Sso` is real old way dong stuff, It giving me deprecation errors, Kindly suggest me latest working alternatives,

Comment: @AshishKamble did you find an alternative ?

Comment: @DiegoRamos no man sorry